# Freeze issue when changing dual monitor settings multiple times

Tags: monitors

I have a dual monitor setup and whenever I make changes to monitor settings a couple of times, my computer freezes.

When I change a monitor setting (like mirror, resolution or even just close/open my laptop lid) the first time, the monitors switch/adjust quickly. The second time, there's like a 2 second lag before switching/adjusting. The third time, there's a large lag > 10 seconds (or sometimes freeze). The next time, the computer freezes. Nothing is displayed on the screen and I'm barely able to move the cursor. Even switching to a tty takes a LOT of time and it's very very slow.

I'm running the latest version of Zorin with GNOME. Here's some info on the monitors:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.97*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```